# linux header file how to edit gcc code

Tags: linux, gcc, kernel

my vm system is ubuntu 16.04, and i have download the kernel header files,i have write the code，but don't know how to edit gcc code or Makefile

```
#include <linux/netdevice.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(){
    struct net_device *dev = dev_base;
    struct in_device *mydevice;
    struct in_ifaddr *myifaddr;
    while( dev != NULL ){
        printf("dev name: %s\n", dev->name);
        mydevice = dev->ip_ptr;
        myifaddr = mydevice->ifa_list;
        while(myifaddr != NULL){
            printf("ip: %s\n", inet_ntoa((struct in_addr)(myifaddr->ifa_local)));
            myifaddr = myifaddr->ifa_next;
        }
        dev = dev->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

if i use gcc test.c it will come out some error like this

```
yq@ubuntu:~/test$ gcc test.c 
In file included from /usr/include/linux/netdevice.h:28:0,
                 from test.c:1:
/usr/include/linux/if.h:234:19: error: field ‘ifru_addr’ has incomplete type
   struct sockaddr ifru_addr;
                   ^
......

test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:8:27: error: ‘dev_base’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  struct net_device *dev = dev_base;
```

Comment: Looks like you didn't set any of the usual `CFLAGS` - as well as `-Werror -Wextra`, you also need to use `-I` to specify include directories.  But what are you doing trying to use `net_device` and the like from user code?

Comment: Mixing user-space headers (`stdio.h`) and kernel-space ones (`linux/netdevice.h`) never works. You should decide which code do you want to write - user or kernel one.

Comment: thanks first, i use the kernel 2.6 to printk the ipaddr of each netdevice, but i don't know how to get the dev_base, the book said that the dev_base is a global variable, but its failed when i use "extern struct net_device *dev_base;" to get it